# explicitly call TEIID function

Tags: teiid

I would like to explicitly call a TEIID function instead of having it pushdown...

Is there a way for me to explicitly call org.jboss.teiid.row_number() over (order by x), so that the row_number() function is at the TEIID layer, instead of getting pushed down to the underlying datasource?

I've used translator overrides previously to force federation and execution of sql outer joins at the TEIID layer by setting SupportsOuterJoins=false, but I don't see anything specific to over() clauses, and I was hoping there was a way to explicitly tell TEIID to do row_number() on the result set after it is returned

Thank you,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

try "SupportsElementaryOlapOperations=false" to turn off the RANK, DENSE_RANK, and ROW_NUMBER functions.

Comment: that was actually the first thing I tried it looks like these operations are not exposed in the translator and I had to override in order to turn it off... https://github.com/teiid/teiid/blob/9.3.x/connectors/jdbc/translator-hive/src/main/java/org/teiid/translator/hive/HiveExecutionFactory.java#L187